# Anything for deciding default paper size based on locale?

Tags: java, locale

Within Java, is there anything that I can use out of box to decide the default paper size based on locale?

I am building a web application and need to generate a PDF document. Its size can be letter, legal, A4, etc., depending on the locale. From the web application, I can get the visitor's locale info such as country, etc.

Comment: Letter and A3 are very, very different sizes.

Comment: I presume you lean `U.S. Letter` vs `A4`.

Comment: Boris, thanks. I changed A3 to A4.

Comment: Java has printing APIs -- maybe they expose the default paper size?

Comment: What do you mean by based on locale?

Comment: By locale, I mean that I can obtain the locale (with info such as country, etc.) from a web application and from it I can generate a PDF with size fit for the region of that locale .

Comment: Europe including the UK, uses A4.  The US, as ever, is different.  I do not know about the rest of the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[java.awt.PageAttributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/PageAttributes.html) has a method called [setMediaToDefault()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/PageAttributes.html#setMediaToDefault()) which should do just that.

If you believe its javadoc:

> The default size for locales in the United States and Canada is MediaType.NA_LETTER. The default size for all other locales is MediaType.ISO_A4.

So, if you want to <strike>steal</strike> borrow its implementation:

```
public void setMediaToDefault(){
    String defaultCountry = Locale.getDefault().getCountry();
    if (defaultCountry != null &&
        (defaultCountry.equals(Locale.US.getCountry()) ||
         defaultCountry.equals(Locale.CANADA.getCountry()))) {
        setMedia(MediaType.NA_LETTER);
    } else {
        setMedia(MediaType.ISO_A4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mureinik, thanks for your info. If the whole world uses either LETTER (US and Canada) or A4 (the rest). Then it should be simple enough. Cheers.